# Azure function write_dataframe_to_datalake in python working fine on VScode but fails when deployed to the cloud

Tags: python, azure, function, visual-studio-code, serverless

I am new to Azure functions and am trying to write a function (Blobtrigger), the function reads the file uploaded on the blob (the file is binary .dat file), does some conversions to convert the data as a pandas data frame and then converts it to .parquet file format and saves it on the azure datalake.
Everything works well when I am locally running the function in VSCode, but when I upload it on the azure cloud functions, I get an error and the function fails.

After looking into the code and checking each step by individually uploading on cloud, I have found that the code works fine till converting the .dat file to dataframe, but fails when I add the function to save it to datalake. I am using the following function found in microsoft tutorials.

```
def write_dataframe_to_datalake(df, datalake_service_client, filesystem_name, dir_name, filename):
    file_path = f'{dir_name}/{filename}'

    file_client = datalake_service_client.get_file_client(filesystem_name, file_path)

    processed_df = df.to_parquet(index=False)

    file_client.upload_data(data=processed_df,overwrite=True, length=len(processed_df))

    file_client.flush_data(len(processed_df))

    return True
```

reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/tutorial-deploy-serverless-cloud-etl-05

This function works fine on azure cloud, when I run it indiviually but not with my converted dataframe.

Can anyone identify what the problem could be. Thanks a lot!

Comment: May I know what is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the Error message we can identify the issue but when Azure function is working fine locally it should work after the deployment as well. In few cases after deploying our function we will get internal server errors when we run our code.

Below are two ways we can get rid of it.

- Add Application Settings ( Add all the variables from local.settings.json under Configurations )

[image]

- If our Azure function is interacting with any of Azure Storage Service or Blob storage we need to add the API link in CORS, or you can try adding “*” which means allowing all).
  [image]

Refer to this [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-azure-function-app-settings?tabs=portal) for adding Application Settings

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The error was solved by giving the version for pandas in the requirements file. My dataframe had a datetime column and df.to_parquet was unable to convert that column when deployed on the azure functions.